# Computation of Jacobian matrix in cvRodrigues2

Tags: opencv, math, matrix, derivative

I'm reading source code of opencv: `cvProjectPoints2`, `cvRodrigues2`.

In `cvProjectPoints2`, the Jacobian matrix is first got using `cvRodrigues2( &_r, &matR, &_dRdr );`, and then used to calculate the partial derivative of pixels w.r.t the **rvec** (axis-angle representation)。

```
if( dpdr_p )
{
    double dx0dr[] =
    {
        X*dRdr[0] + Y*dRdr[1] + Z*dRdr[2],
        X*dRdr[9] + Y*dRdr[10] + Z*dRdr[11],
        X*dRdr[18] + Y*dRdr[19] + Z*dRdr[20]
    };
    double dy0dr[] =
    {
        X*dRdr[3] + Y*dRdr[4] + Z*dRdr[5],
        X*dRdr[12] + Y*dRdr[13] + Z*dRdr[14],
        X*dRdr[21] + Y*dRdr[22] + Z*dRdr[23]
    };
    double dz0dr[] =
    {
        X*dRdr[6] + Y*dRdr[7] + Z*dRdr[8],
        X*dRdr[15] + Y*dRdr[16] + Z*dRdr[17],
        X*dRdr[24] + Y*dRdr[25] + Z*dRdr[26]
    };
    for( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
    {
        double dxdr = z*(dx0dr[j] - x*dz0dr[j]);
        double dydr = z*(dy0dr[j] - y*dz0dr[j]);
        double dr2dr = 2*x*dxdr + 2*y*dydr;
        double dcdist_dr = k[0]*dr2dr + 2*k[1]*r2*dr2dr + 3*k[4]*r4*dr2dr;
        double dicdist2_dr = -icdist2*icdist2*(k[5]*dr2dr + 2*k[6]*r2*dr2dr + 3*k[7]*r4*dr2dr);
        double da1dr = 2*(x*dydr + y*dxdr);
        double dmxdr = fx*(dxdr*cdist*icdist2 + x*dcdist_dr*icdist2 + x*cdist*dicdist2_dr +
                           k[2]*da1dr + k[3]*(dr2dr + 2*x*dxdr));
        double dmydr = fy*(dydr*cdist*icdist2 + y*dcdist_dr*icdist2 + y*cdist*dicdist2_dr +
                           k[2]*(dr2dr + 2*y*dydr) + k[3]*da1dr);
        dpdr_p[j] = dmxdr;
        dpdr_p[dpdr_step+j] = dmydr;
    }
    dpdr_p += dpdr_step*2;
}
```

The shape of `dRdr` is **3*9**, and from how the indices of `dRdr` is used:

```
X*dRdr[0] + Y*dRdr[1] + Z*dRdr[2], //-> dx0dr1
X*dRdr[9] + Y*dRdr[10] + Z*dRdr[11], //-> dx0dr2
X*dRdr[18] + Y*dRdr[19] + Z*dRdr[20] //-> dx0dr3
```

the Jacobian matrix seems to be:

```
dR1/dr1, dR2/dr1, ..., dR9/dr1,
dR1/dr2, dR2/dr2, ..., dR9/dr2,
dR1/dr3, dR2/dr3, ..., dR9/dr3,
```

But to my knowledge the Jacobian matrix should be of shape **9*3**, since it's derivatives of **R(1~9)** w.r.t **r(1~3)**:

```
dR1/dr1, dR1/dr2, dR1/dr3,
dR2/dr1, dR2/dr2, dR2/dr3,
...
...
dR9/dr1, dR9/dr2, dR9/dr3,
```

As the [docs of `cvRodrigues2`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#rodrigues) says:

> **jacobian** – Optional output Jacobian matrix, 3x9 or 9x3, which is a
>   matrix of partial derivatives of the output array components with
>   respect to the input array components.

So am I misunderstanding the code & docs? Or is the code using other convention? Or is it a bug (not likely...)?

Comment: Should have clarify the "3x9 or 9x3" part in the docs..

Comment: You are indeed right with respect to math definition, I'll lookup what that part means

Comment: Any updates about this topic? I have the same issue when I use cv2.Rodrigues() function. When I pass a rotation vector, I get a rotation matrix as output and a 3x9 Jacobian instead of a 9x3.

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the docs:

```
src – Input rotation vector (3x1 or 1x3) or rotation matrix (3x3).
dst – Output rotation matrix (3x3) or rotation vector (3x1 or 1x3), respectively.
jacobian – Optional output Jacobian matrix, 3x9 or 9x3, which is a matrix of partial derivatives of the output array components with respect to the input array components.
```

As you see you can switch source and destination places(mathematically it will be exactly transposition), **but** the code does not account for it.

Therefore, indeed you've got a transposed Jacobian, because you switched first arguments places(from default places for their types). Switch them again, and you'll get normal Jacobian!

Comment: what do you mean by *"because you switched first arguments places"*? In my example code, **src** is a rvec (3x1), and **dst** is a rmat (3x3). If your **switch** mean "swap the src & dst", that will NOT get the Jacob-mat transposed, but each element of the matrix changed from `dR/dr` to `dr/dR` to my knowledge.

Comment: Try to do it and post the result.  
It will not change dR/dr to dr/dR for sure per docs, because they explicitly state 3x3 or 3x1 and won't misplace one for another.